# Cannot get my option values to post to email using php

Tags: php, select

hi guys I can't seem to get this to work...

here's the html

```
<form id="quotesform" method="POST" action="quotes.php">
Name:
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<br>
E-Mail:
<input type="text" name="email" size="19"><br>
<br>
Contact Number:
<input type="text" name="number" size="19"><br>
<br>

<label>What type of website?</label>
<select id="websitetype" name="websitetype">
<option value="1">Simple brochure website</option>
<option value="2">ecommerce/shopping website</option>
<option value="3">CMS website</option>
<option value="4">other</option>
</select><br /><br />

<label>How many pages?</label>
<select id="webpages" name="webpages">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2-5</option>
<option value="3">5-10</option>
<option value="4">10-20</option>
<option value="5">20+</option>
</select><br /><br />

Brief description of your project<br>
<textarea rows="9" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

heres the php

```
$emailSubject = 'quoteformprocess!'; 
$webMaster = 'admin@wheretogetawebsite.co.uk';


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$websitetype = array(1 => "brochure", 2 => "ecommerce", 3=>"cms", 4=>"other");
$websitetype = $agents[(int) $_POST['agents']];
$webpages = array(1 => "1", 2 => "2-5", 3=>"5-10", 4=>"10-20", 5=>"20+");
$webpages = $webpages[(int) $_POST['webpages']];



$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Number: $number <br>
Websitetype: $websitetype <br>
Webpages: $Webpages <br>


EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);


/* Results rendered as HTML */
$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>sent message</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.wheretogetawebsite.co.uk">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-color: #444; /* You can edit this CSS to match your website*/
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fec001;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 200px;
margin-left: 150px;
width: 800px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<div align="center">Put your message in here letting the sender know the message has      been successfully sent</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

here what the email looks like

Name: gary 
Email: garyjr25@hotmail.co.uk 
Number: 123 
Websitetype: 
Webpages:

Im sure the answer is simple but im new to php and cannot seem to get my head around it, thanks for any help it's greatly appreciated

Comment: Is that what you _want_ the email to look like, or what it _does_ look like? We would need to know both.

Comment: You can start by fixing the `$websitetype` part. It looks for values in an `$agents` array, but it's not defined?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were intending

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$agents = array(1 => "brochure", 2 => "ecommerce", 3=>"cms", 4=>"other");
$websitetype = $agents[(int) $_POST['websitetype']];
$webpages = array(1 => "1", 2 => "2-5", 3=>"5-10", 4=>"10-20", 5=>"20+");
$webpages = $webpages[(int) $_POST['webpages']];
```

You were using the `agents` key in the POST array when I think you wanted websitetype

Comment: That's one part of the story (regarding the `websitetype`). However, why isn't the `Webpages` part being properly printed out?

Comment: He is using capital W for `$Webpages` when he tries to print it but lower case when he stores it

Comment: Well, to be honest I had noticed both vars not being printed out, but I really couldn't figure out what could be going wrong with that second one... lousy bugs! lol ;-)

Comment: it doesn't help that capital W and lowercase w look so similar in that font either

Comment: hi guys ignore the "agents" they should be "websitetype" my bad i put it together with some other code ive found on the net. I just want the options to be sent to my email, im not concerned what they look like just for the information to be sent. I'm a complete noob to php lol as you have probably guessed

Answer (score 1):

```
$websitetype = $agents[(int) $_POST['agents']];
```

should be

```
$websitetype = $websitetype[(int) $_POST['websitetype']];
```

It looks like you just forgot to change it from an old version or something. And also, PHP variables are case-sensitive, so

```
Webpages: $Webpages <br>
```

should be

```
Webpages: $webpages <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) There is a typo(?) here :

```
$websitetype = array(1 => "brochure", 2 => "ecommerce", 3=>"cms", 4=>"other");
$websitetype = $agents[(int) $_POST['agents']];
```

- Obviously you wanted sth like : `$websitetype[$_POST['websitetype']];`

2) Another typo here :

`$Webpages` (when printing out the var)

- Replace it with `$webpages` (ALL LOWERCASE - no capital first letter)

Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like websitetype and agents are mixed up.

PHP variable names are case sensitive so $Webpages is not $webpages.